# List not beign assigned as a parameter Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url.action

I'm using Url.Action to pass some paramenters to a method, like this

```
//Sending data
<a href="@Url.Action("BorrarMensaje", "Supplier", new { idMsg = item.IDMensaje, idMsgUsr = item.IDMensajeUsuario, idImg = item.IDImagen, idsArchs = item.IDArchivos })" class="btn btn-danger">Sí</a>
```

```
//Method
public ActionResult BorrarMensaje(int idMsg, int idMsgUsr, int idImg, List<int> idsArchs)
        {
            tblMensaje tblMensaje = db.tblMensaje.Find(idMsg);
            tblMensajesUsuario tblMensajesUsuario = db.tblMensajesUsuario.Find(idMsgUsr);
            tblImagenAdj tblImagenAdj = db.tblImagenAdj.Find(idImg);

            foreach (var id in idsArchs)
            {
                tblArchivoAdj tblArchivoAdj = db.tblArchivoAdj.Find(id);
                db.tblArchivoAdj.Remove(tblArchivoAdj);
            }
//Some more code...
```

The values of idMsg, idMsgUsr, idImg are sent as arguments, but idsArch just doesn´t get the value of IDArchivos, when I view the count property it shows 0, (both idsArch and IDArchivos are of type List), I don't know why it isn't working, is there any alternative to do this? Thanks beforehand

Comment: will you include the model/class for idArchs? what are its properties?

Answer (score 0):

For alternatives; you could write it as a Form and fields are hidden.

```
<form method="GET" action="@Url.Action("BorrarMensaje", "Supplier")">
   <input name="idMsg" value="@item.IDMensage" hidden />
   <input name="idMsgUsr" value="@item.IDMensajeUsuario" hidden />
   <input name="idImg" value="@item.IDImagen" hidden />

   <!-- for type list, you need to loop and specify an index -->
   
   @for(int i = 0; i < item.IDArchivos.Count(); i++){
      
      <!--replace PropertyName with the property name of IDArchivos that you want to submit -->
      <input name="idsArchs[@i].PropertyName" hidden />
      
      <input class="btn btn-danger" type="Submit" value="Si">
   }
</form>
```

No changes in controller.